# how to rearrange randomly and show all the 5 elements

Tags: php, cakephp

how can I rearrange it randomly and NOT use shuffle function and still be able to randomly arrange all the elements

```
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");   
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);   
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";   
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";   
echo $input[$rand_keys[2]] . "\n";   
echo $input[$rand_keys[3]] . "\n";   
echo $input[$rand_keys[4]] . "\n";
```

so it shows random names everytime the function is ran. thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with shuffle? and didn't you already answer your own question?

Comment: Thats just the code from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Don't help him! He's trying to implement the Matrix!  ;)

Comment: @Beska: You mean he wants to create a Matrix inside the Matrix ? Geez... ( ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please expand on your question. Are you trying to render 5 elements, but in a random order?

You can pass variables into your elements so perhaps you can pass a `rand()` into it, to change the output.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/314/Views

```
$this->renderElement('helpbox', array("helptext" => "Oh, this text is very helpful."));
```

Then you could switch on `$helptext` in your element.

Alternatively, you could just switch the `$this->renderElement()` call by wrapping it in some randomising php.